# How to find tension in the cantilever brakes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

From *Mechanics of Materials* by JM Gere, Ed. **2009**, problem 1.2.3:

> (**b**) For each braking system, what is the stress in the brake cable (assume effective cross-sectional area of $0.00167\,\rm in.^2$)? (HINT: Because of symmetry, you only need to use the right half of each figure in your analysis.)
>
> [image]

In the left side example of cantilever brakes, how do I find the tension in strings $DE$ and $DC$, in terms of $T$. According to me applying force balance equations, horizontal and vertical forces should be zero, i.e.

$$T_{DE} \cos{45} + T_{DE} \cos{45} = T$$

The answer given is $T/2$, which is against general understanding.

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable to me. I would also arrive at $T/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I think there might be some conceptual error related to some constraints maybe, because otherwise its a fairly simple problem.

Comment: Maybe. Seems like a straightforward application of Newton's 2nd law to the upper clip to me, though.

Comment: Hint: what must $T_{DCv}$ and $T_{DEv}$ be to balance the purely vertical $TD$ ?  Then, what must $T_{DC}$ (total) be?

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't get your logic, why should i solve it that way?

Comment: Any suggestions regarding the question, i can prove the authenticity of the answer, if anyone requires.

Comment: Possible overkill, but detailed analysis:  http://www.circleacycles.com/cantilevers/canti-geometry.pdf

Comment: $T/\sqrt{2}$ looks indeed to be the answer. I'm struggling to see anything else.